# vue-i18n calling t(key, parameterArray) does not fill in (interpolate) value of parameter

Tags: vue.js, localization, translation, vue-i18n

I am trying to translate some error messages in my Vue application.

Regular messages work fine, the labels are translated accordingly.

However, when I try to pass arguments to the translation, the translated parameter (`{0}`) remains un-replaced by the given value.

The code requires that the translated string is passed further to a different component, so I am using `t` and not `$t` to translate the message.

The code that uses the translation is:

```
  addMessage(myMessage: TranslatedMessage) {
    this.furtherSendTranslatedComponent(destination, {
        content: i18n.global.t(myMessage.message, myMessage.args),
      })
   
    if (myMessage.args != null && myMessage.args.length > 0) {
      alert(myMessage.message)
      alert(i18n.global.t(myMessage.message, myMessage.args))
      alert(myMessage.args)
    }   
  }
```

Now, this works just fine for messages that do not have parameters, but if there is a parameter in the message resources, the text remains un-replaced.

Say, I have a file `resources.properties` with content:

```
my.first.message=The planet that you are looking for is unknown
my.second.message=The planet {0} that you are looking for is unknown
```

The component (and the `alert()` I placed to try to figure things out) displays the message as-is, without parameter interpolation:  `"The planet {0} that you are looking for is unknown"`

So, I am shown in the alerts, respectively:

`my.second.message`

`The planet {0} that you are looking for is unknown`

`Venuz`

It is clear that the parameter array is sent. I can clearly see in the console output, the values sent:

```
args: ['Venuz']
message:"my.second.message"
```

But why does the interpolation not take place?